# How to call an applet from another Java file?

Tags: java, applet

I have a Java file and from that I want to call an applet file.

How to do it?

Comment: It's going thr all the method printing all msg inthose methods but jst not displaying the applet?

Answer (score 0):

You need something to display the applet in, it won’t show itself miraculously somewhere.

```
JFrame frame = new JFrame();
frame.getContentPane().add(applet);
frame.setVisible(true);
```

Comment: This might work, but you'd probably want to act like an applet container, calling init() and start(), stop() and destroy() appropriately.